# Angular 4 Service not initialized when accessing method

Tags: angular, typescript, service, httpclient, asynchronous

I have an Angular 4 app containing a I18n service that asynchronously retrieves a json file in its constructor using the HttpClient. When the json is retrieved it is assigned to an object.

The I18n service exposes getKeyValue() method to retrieve a value from this object. One of my components calls in ngOnInit() the I18n service `getKeyValue('about-card-text')` method to retrieve a specific text.

But that throws an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'about-card-text' of undefined
```

`Undefined` being the object that should contain the json.

I *expected* that the service first asynchronously retrieves the json file before its `getKeyValue()` method is being called, but what actually *happens* is that the service method is already called before the service finished initializing and the json file is loaded.

Changing the calling in the component to
`SetTimeOut(() => getKeyValue('about-card-text'), 100)`

makes it work but this is a hack.

I could subscribe to the HttpClient Observable in the Component but I 
want to prevent outsourcing logic to the calling components regarding the server initialization. I just want to keep all logic regarding I18n service in the service and just have components access the public API by calling `getKeyValue()`.

Is that possible and what is the solution here???

Thanks,

Marc

Comment: Code descriptions never work. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the case you're talking about.

Comment: Loading the file is asynchronous.So loading a ley in the file should be asynchronous, too. getKeyValue() should return a promise or an observable.I suggest not reinventing your own i18n and use either the native support in Angular, or ngx-translate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This question is not about my own implementation of an I18n service. Rather I want to know how to deal with services that initialize asynchronously. I believe Angular has a (poorly documented) feature: APP_INITIALIZER. http://www.learn-angular.fr/how-to-call-an-asynchronous-service-before-bootstrap/

Comment: Showing a bit more of your code would help tremendously. In most cases, handling async just means ensuring your `subscribe` is in the right place and contains the appropriate functions. We can't comment on that more specifically without seeing a bit more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my own question through this great tutorial on using the APP_INITIALIZER token in Angular 4: [https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/#runtime-configuration]